# Where in the SFDX tree do translations (changed labels) for actions like LoginToNetworkAsUser go?

Tags: metadata, translation, translation-workbench

These are Digital Experience related buttons that can appear on the Contact record. The buttons are normally labelled:

- `LoginToNetworkAsUser` has label "Login to Experience as User"
- `EnableCustomerPortal` has label "Enable Customer User"
- `DisableCustomerPortal` has label "Disable Customer User"

I'm looking for a way to change these labels.

When doing a:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p ...
```

on this metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <quickActions>
        <aspect>Master</aspect>
        <label>KC LoginToNetworkAsUser</label>
        <name>LoginToNetworkAsUser</name>
    </quickActions>
    <quickActions>
        <aspect>Master</aspect>
        <label>KC EnableCustomerPortal</label>
        <name>EnableCustomerPortal</name>
    </quickActions>
    <quickActions>
        <aspect>Master</aspect>
        <label>KC DisableCustomerPortal</label>
        <name>DisableCustomerPortal</name>
    </quickActions>
</CustomObjectTranslation>
```

these errors results:

```
 Type    Name          Problem                                                                           
 ─────── ───────────── ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── 
 Warning Contact-en_US In field: name - no QuickAction named Contact.EnableCustomerPortal found (8:19)   
 Warning Contact-en_US In field: name - no QuickAction named Contact.LoginToNetworkAsUser found (3:19)   
 Warning Contact-en_US In field: name - no QuickAction named Contact.DisableCustomerPortal found (13:19)
```

Is there some way these labels can be changed in the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where translations appear:

- .../translations/*language*.translation - where custom label translations appear.
- .../objectTranslations/*object*-*language*/... - where schema label translations appear.
- .../globalValueSetTranslations/*valueSetName*-*language*.globalValueSetTranslation - where global value set entry translations appear.

There are probably others. I believe quick action labels appear in the custom label translations (that's what it looks like from what we have packaged).

By way of example, we have a flow-based quick action called "JobOrderCloneRateCard". Searching for this I see the following:

[image: JobOrderCloneRateCard flow-based quick action and translations]

Comment: Thanks Phil; I've been looking in those areas. The 3 labels I'm interested in are not listed by default in Custom Labels. I'll try adding.

Comment: Indeed, they are not, as you can see from the above example - our `.../labels/CustomLabels.labels` file is not listed. They only need to appear in the translation versions I believe (and should not be added to the CustomLabels).